# Close all the service broker connections

Tags: t-sql, service-broker

I'm trying to get all the conversation handlers to get closed, before killing the service broker.

I see that in the code above I cannot quite get the guid for conversation_handler (If I debug I see it has an empty value shown as {...}).

Furthermore, sometimes the @@ROWCOUNT returns 1 (even when the queried queue table is empty).

Am I missing something about how to retrieve output parameters using sp_executesql ?

```
set rowcount 1
--ITERATORS
declare @ServiceName varchar(100)
select @ServiceName = ServiceName from #services_and_queues
declare @QueueName varchar(100)
select @QueueName = QueueName from #services_and_queues
declare @IsMsShipped bit
select @IsMsShipped = IsMsShipped from #services_and_queues
while @@rowcount <> 0
begin
    set rowcount 0
    --SYSTEM QUEUES CANNOT BE CHANGED, NOR THE SERVICES ASSOCIATED WITH THEM
    if( @IsMsShipped = 0)
    BEGIN
        --END ALL THE CONVERSATIONS FOR THE CURRENT QUEUE
        declare @conversation_handler uniqueidentifier
        while(1=1)
        begin
            DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) =  N'select top 1 @conversation_handler = conversation_handle from  ' + @QueueName
            exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@conversation_handler uniqueidentifier out', @conversation_handler out
            if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0 or @conversation_handler = null or trim(CAST(@conversation_handler AS char(36))) = '')
                break
            end conversation @conversation_handler with cleanup
        end



    END
    delete #services_and_queues where ServiceName = @ServiceName
    set rowcount 1
    select @ServiceName = ServiceName from #services_and_queues
    select @QueueName = QueueName from #services_and_queues

    select @IsMsShipped = IsMsShipped from #services_and_queues
end
set rowcount 0
DROP TABLE #services_and_queues
```

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE ... SET NEW_BROKER` ?

Comment: Thanks, I wish it was that simple, we tried that and it did not quite work in this context (CI of multiple applications sharing the db server)